# Integrate vuex into express-vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

Im using express-vue (https://github.com/express-vue/express-vue)

(A package that should do the ssr for me).

Now I wanted to integrate vuex into my project and I'm little confused on how to do that. 
I can use the cdn link, but I dont know where I should put this code:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       count: 0
    },
 mutations: {
    increment (state) {
        state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

(from here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getting-started.html) 
So that vuex is availible in every component(and mixins if possible) of mine.

(If you have a good suggestion on the usage of npm packages in express-vue I would be happy too, but as far as I know node-modules is not availible for express-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet. 
As their core team said:

> Support for vuex and other plugins is coming in express-vue@5
>
> It’s been prematurely published so please don’t use it just yet. But
>   yes soon.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Thought it was possible because I was able to integrate some features that supported cdn links. Do you have any idea when this update might be released?

Comment: I am sure as soon as possible

Comment: By the way, @telion, was my answer helpful?

Comment: well you answered the question^^. I wanted to use it to control the variables on the client. Its getting anoying to bind and emit them for every component, and I will need mixins also to have acces to them.

Comment: but Sorry I forgot to mark it as the answer. My bad.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is to use another variants to build server-side rendering with Vue.js

Comment: But, again, I understand that it will take a time to rewrite the project